# Putting graph on a grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, grid, graph-algorithm

I have a directed graph with no loops with the following additional information:

- Every vertex has outdegree at most 4.
- Every edge is labeled 'up', 'right', 'down' or 'left'.
- If there is an 'up' edge from A to B, then there is a 'down' edge from B to A (i.e. it is symmetric).
- All edges which start at the same vertex have different labels.

I am looking for an algorithm that would assign 2d integer coordinates to each vertex, such that y(B) > y(A) whenever there is an 'up' edge from A to B, and similarly for other types of edges. Moreover, edges should not intersect.

For example, this is a picture of such a graph with 8 vertices:

```
1-------2---3
|           |
|   4       |
|   |       |
5---6---7---8
```

Note, that y(4) < y(1), since otherwise there would be intersecting edges.

I realize that the solution is far from unique, so one may require the result to have the minimal size in some sense.

Comment: This isn't always possible, because I could link the nodes in a ring where every node is to the left of some other node.  For example, A's left pointer is B, whose right pointer is back to A.  Then, B's left pointer is to A, whose right pointer is back to B.  There's no way to lay this out in a grid.  What other properties of the graph may we assume to ensure that this can't happen?

Comment: It's true, so I'm assuming that the solution exists. If it doesn't, I would like to have as little edge intersections as possible (in your example it's 1). Perhaps, the algorithm could remove such extra edges.